# Two pointers pointing to the same address

Tags: c++, c, pointers

What happens when two pointers are pointing to the same address? Is this going to cause a security problem?

Comment: ...nothing happens. What problem(s) are you experiencing? What code have you written?

Comment: @Cody Gray . Its just for my interest

Comment: What happens when someone is known by two different names?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: it depends on the context and details.

Answer (score 13):

The fact itself is ok, but you'll run into undefined behavior if you call `delete` on one of the pointers and attempt to use the other afterwards:

```
int* x = new int(5);
int* y = x;
delete x;
//y is a dangling pointer
```

If you run into a situation where you have to use multiple pointers to the same memory address, you should look into **smart pointers**.

Comment: I think pointer dangling vulnerability happens when we use delete on one of the pointers and attempt to use the other afterwards.

Comment: @DaneshjuM that's exactly what I said...

Comment: what if we do not use delete and just pointing to same address?

Comment: Another important case is a double free/delete of a pointer. And that can have security implications in addition to reliability issues.

Comment: x is also still dangling pointer until you assign NULL.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe to have more than one pointer to the same address, but make sure that you know that if the memory is deleted using `delete` or if the original variable goes out of scope, further access to it will be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Depends:

**For Classic (Non-Smart) Pointers**: You can have more than one pointers to point to the same memory location but manipulating the location would be percolated across all the pointers. Deleting/Freeing the storage of one pointer would cause undefined behavior when other pointers are being used. Note the best practice is to make a pointer NULL once the storage is freed to prevent double delete and when using multiple pointers this is not pragmatically plausible.

### Smart Pointers

**Auto_Pointers(C++98)**: C++ template class implementation provided a mechanism to allow one and only one pointer to point to one memory location. Generally as these pointers are implemented on stack as object, when they come out of scope the address would automatically be freed. But copy assignment of one pointer to another would make the other unusable.

**Shared_Pointers(C++2003 TR1)**: Boost library provided shared pointers which has a reference count which determines when the object could be freed. This is better than auto_ptrs as you can have multiple usable pointers sharing the same memory location.

**Unique_Pointers(C++11)**: Similar to Auto_pointers, but inherit the concept of transfer of ownership where assignment and copy constructor are not exposed. Instead a move method is implemented to make it more clear what the intention is.

Answer (score 3):

If both pointers are of the same type, there is no issue:

```
int a = 42;
int *p = &a
int *q = p;
*p = 3145;   // no problem, a and *q are now also equal 3145
```

If both pointers are of different types (with the exception of `char *`) and point to the same object, dereferencing one of the pointer is undefined behavior.

```
float a = 42.0f;
float *p = &a;
int *q = (int *) p;  // we assume pointer is correctly aligned
*q = 0;              // undefined behavior, it breaks aliasing rules
```

These rules are known as the C pointers aliasing rules. You can find a list of the C aliasing rules in [n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) in paragraph 6.5p7.

Answer (score 0):

Both the objects are pointing to same heap address.

At the time when you will de-allocate memory then it may cause problems to other objects pointing to same address.

Comment: Pointers don't necessarily point to the heap.

Comment: tnx all . according to what I understood we have to make impossible to gain access to deleted pointer address