# array of pointers pointing the same variable

Tags: c, arrays

Can all the pointer members of an array point to the same variable?
ex: What happens when `*a[i]` is pointed to a variable `C` of value `5` and the length of the array is `3`? Will `a[0],a[1],a[2]` have the values `5`?

Comment: The length of the array has nothing to do with what each element points to. If you assign the same address in each pointer in a pointer array, then by definition of how pointers work, they will all point to the same data. And your question would make a LOT more sense if it had actual *code*, properly formatted and demonstrating what you're having problems understanding.

Comment: No a[0],a[1],a[2] will not point to variable C, you have to explicitly make make them point to variable C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371367/1971401)

> If all pointers are of the same type, there is no issue

```
int a = 10;
int *b[3];

b[0] = &a;
b[1] = &a;
b[2] = &a;

a = 5; // now b[0-2] are also equal 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

No a[0],a[1],a[2] will not point to variable C, you have to explicitly make them point to variable C. Consider below example.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
    int *a[3];
    int c=5;
    a[0] = &c;
    printf("%d %d %d", *a[0],*a[1],*a[2]);//this will print 5 junkvalue junkvalue

    a[1] = &c;
    a[2] = &c;

    printf("%d %d %d", *a[0],*a[1],*a[2]);//this will print 5 5 5

     }
```